# Primefaces piechart export button not working properly

Tags: primefaces, pie-chart, jqplot

I want to export my primefaces piechart as an image, and I followed [Primefaces Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/export.xhtml) for doing so. The problem is when I click the export button, the window freezes and the chart is not exported as an image, hence I cannot right click and save it. I have tried the solutions given in [PrimeFaces: export chart as picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292020/primefaces-export-chart-as-picture) and [.Cannot export chart as image in Primefaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358944/cannot-export-chart-as-image-in-primefaces?rq=1) but could not solve my problem. Below is my code:

```
    <p:panelGrid id="subPanelGrid" columns="1" style="width:100%" layout="grid">
    <table style="width: 50%;">
        <tr>
            <td><p:column>
                    <div dir="ltr" class="chartContainer">
                        <p:chart type="pie" model="#{myExample.myPieChart}" style="width:600px;height:340px" widgetVar="chart" />

                        <p:commandButton type="button" value="Export" icon="ui-icon-extlink" onclick="exportChart()" />

                        <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fade" modal="true" header="Chart as an Image" resizable="false">
                            <p:outputPanel id="output" layout="block" style="width:600px;height:340px" />
                        </p:dialog>
                    </div>
                </p:column></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</p:panelGrid>
```

And here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function exportChart() {
                    $('#output').empty()
                            .append(PF('chart').exportAsImage());
                    PF('dlg').show();
                }
            </script>
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Does it fail in all browsers?

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes. I tried it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Then two things remain (which should be done initially). Post version info and post a [mcve]

Comment: @Kukeltje my code is the exact above code, so I guess that qualifies as my example as well.
I'm using Primefaces 6.1.11 and jsf 2.2.16.

Comment: It might be your code, it might be an example, but it is not complete nor minimal (did you actually read the link that was posted?) Also read [ask] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: @Kukeltje I did read the link, but the example is just as much as it is in the [primefaces showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/export.xhtml) and I think I have this problem in the first place because the showcase example is minimal, yet I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The PF showcase  is sort of minimal, yes but it is not complete. You still need to adhere to basic jsf rules which they, for brevity, do not show and assume you are aware of. It's a PF showcase not a JSF tutorial. What did you debug? Do other charts work? Etc

Comment: @Kukeltje the charts work fine, I just have problem with exporting them. And my code for exporting the charts is the few lines above, same as the showcase. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does **exporting** other charts fail too  (since you have piechart in your title)

Comment: @Kukeltje I don't have other charts in my code, but I added a line chart for the test, and it failed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a recurrent problem with primefaces... If your are using primefaces 5 or +, you can try (as your grid is not in a form)

```js
function exportChart() {
  $('#output').empty().append(chart.exportAsImage());
  dlg.show();
}
```

It exists other ways as described here [PrimeFaces: export chart as picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292020/primefaces-export-chart-as-picture)

---

Consider trying the following, according to @CycDemo (I have not tried it but people seem to have upVote it):

Download jquery.js and html2canvas.js. If you are using maven just add to your pom.xml in your dependecies:

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>html2canvas</artifactId>
  <version>0.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Then in your .xhtml

```html
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="#{request.contextPath}/js/jquery.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/js/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="imageFrom">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function saveAsImage() { 
                html2canvas($("#imageFrom\\:barChart"), {
                    onrendered: function(canvas) {
                        theCanvas = canvas;
                        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                        $("#imageFrom\\:output").append(canvas);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
        <p:chart type="bar" id="barChart" model="#{chartView.barModel}" style="width:500px;height:300px;"/>     
        <p:commandButton id="btnSave" value="Export" onclick="saveAsImage();PF('eventDialog').show();"/>
        <p:dialog id="eventDialog" widgetVar="eventDialog" resizable="false" width="520" height="300" appendToBody="true">
            <p:outputPanel id="output"/>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: How can it be a bug in PF 5+ if it works for me? And adding and additional jquery that does not come with PF will result in errors.

Comment: @Kukeltje by a quick look on internet we can see that this is a recurrent issu, I cannot say if it is a bug or not .. I know it did not worked for me when I used `PF('chart')` and  `chart.exportAsImage()` did the job, I cannot tell why. You are very probably right for the jquery, I updated the post.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem when try to export a pie chart to image (other kind of charts, like bars or lines have no problem). I also notice that the error only occurs when atribute 'ShowDataLabels' is set to true.

There is an opened issue in: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/920

Comment: Yeah I was stuck for so long, but the accepted answer worked for me.